# Get Responses from Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, forms, response

I created an Array to make a multi step form.
How do I get the answers filled inside it and insert it in JSON?

Should I put it inside the array objects or can I get it right on the page

```
const formulario = [<Identificacao />, <ValidaçõesAplicaçãoComponente />, <CoreData1 />, <CoreData1Technology />, <CoreData1Usage />, <CoreData2 />, <CoreData2AdditionalInformation />, <Ownership />, <Components />]



export default class InclusaoAplicacao extends React.Component<IInclusaoAplicacaoProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IInclusaoAplicacaoProps> {

    
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.inclusaoAplicacao}>
          <h1 className={styles.titulo}>Inclusão de Aplicação no Planning IT</h1>

          <div>
            {formulario[op]}

          </div>

          <div className={styles.btn}>
            
            <DefaultButton className={styles.btnCancelar} text='Cancelar'/>
            <PrimaryButton text='Próximo' className={styles.btnProximo} onClick={next}/>
            
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: what's means 'op'